# Convert String to Upper from Scratch

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am trying to write a function that converts a string to it's uppercase version. It mostly works, unless it gets towards the end of the alphabet or end of the input string.

Thoughts? Suggestions? Advice?

```
def upper(string):

    length = len(string)
    index_string = 0
    index_ucase = 0
    index_lcase = 0
    uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    while index_string < len(string):
        index_lcase = 0
        while index_lcase < len(lowercase):
            if string[index_string] == lowercase[index_lcase]:
               string = string[:index_string] + uppercase[index_lcase] + string[index_string+1:]
               break
            else:
                index_lcase += 1
        index_string += 1
```

Comment: @WinstonEwert `it mostly works`, so I suppose there is an issue to tackle here.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @njzk2, oh I missed that point.

Comment: @WinstonEwert that being said, I see no problem in that code. I even ran it against a few test cases, seems to do what it is supposed to.

Comment: @minitoto why are you saying that?

Comment: I have no idea what changed, but now it's working. I literally just resaved the file, opened it, and re-opened the terminal - now it works! -__-

Comment: Should I delete this question or should I leave it for people to post suggestions?

Comment: Are you deliberately reinventing the built-in `string.upper()` function?

Comment: … and if so, how "painful" does it need to be to not be considered "cheating"?

Comment: Yes, I am deliberately reinventing it.
I wrote a function that finds lengths of strings from scratch, but for the sake of posting this up here, I opted for the standard len().

Answer (score 3):

> Thoughts? Suggestions? Advice?

Don't do this.

Really.

Don't.

Unless you're playing. Don't. Don't do this.

Why?

**Languages are hard.**

Uppercase to `i` is `I`, right?

You can always go Uppercase letter -> downcase letter -> Uppercase letter, and the output is the same as the input. Right?

Nope. Nope. Nope Nope.

So first of all, your approach doesn't cover anything but ASCII letters. You know what? German has `ä`. `ä` is straight forward. Uppercase `ä` is `Ä`, lowercase `Ä` is `ä` (if you wonder: it sounds like the a in English *sad*).

Also, German has `ß`. `ß` is a lowercase letter. It sounds like a very sharp `s`. Switzerland, though partly speaking German, doesn't have `ß`; they simply use `ss`. So, in German, `ß` only occurs in the middle or at the end of words. This means there's no need for an uppercase version of it; and, thanks to German efficiency, there simply is no uppercase version of it.

You want to write **CANDY STORE** across your store's entrance? In normal capitalization, it's *Süßwarengeschäft* (Sweet-Ware-Store). If you transliterate that into ALL CAPS, it's right and normed to be **SÜSSWARENGESCHÄFT**. Notice the substitution of lowercase `ß` by uppercase `SS`. BAM. No way back. Your word just got one letter longer, and unless you know German orthography (and are sure the shop owner isn't Swiss), there's no way of knowing that if you want to translate things back to lower case, you'll need to use `ß` instead of `ss`.

That is, unless you used something that gives you much more information.

Unicode is something that gives you much more information. A greek Omega `Ω` might be just that -- a long "O" sound, or it might be the unit of electrical resistance, Ohms: `Ω`. Different meanings (though probably looking the same), common enough for Unicode to have to different *codepoints* for these. If you take a big Omega `Ω` in Unicode and use pythons `lower()` on it, it should correctly give you `⍵`. Not so much if you take `u"The resistance of this resistor is 5Ω"` and use `lower` on that: `u"the resistance of this resistor is 5Ω"`.

Hence: don't use simple letter-per-letter translation. It never worked, and it never will.

Comment: I agree with this. There are answers like this all over SO. As long as the OP is using his `upper` function for learning purposes and not for production or any other serious code it's ok. p.s. I was not the down voter

Comment: @PaulRooney: I don't mind the downvote, really! I do think my answer borders on the "content-wise off-topic", but I hope it's useful on a higher level :)

Comment: Thanks for a thoughtful answer. This is exactly the kind of thing (like dates) which seems straightforward at the outset but is much more nuanced and complicated in reality. For instance, the Ohms symbol vs the letter omega. Also, the use of `upper` should be the first option. +1.

Comment: Another example from turkish, the capitalised version of Türkiye is TÜRKİYE, not TÜRKIYE.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a dict:

```
letters = {'a': 'A'... 'z': 'Z'}
```

Then:

```
def upper(s):
  r = ''
  for i in s:
    if i in letters:
      r = r + letters[i]
    else:
      r = r + i
  return r
```

I think these should solve your problem. Where exactly does your code fail?

Comment: so you suggest a solution to a problem, but you don't know what the problem is? original.

Comment: It's working now. I just restarted stuff and now it's working fine...ugh. How do I delete this question?

Or I could keep it posted for people to post suggestions - thank you by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. I would use a simpler approach

```
import string 
def upper(instring='abacbba'):
    char_map = {l:u for l,u in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase)}
    return "".join([map[char] if char in char_map.keys() else char for char in instring])
```

This would work for ascii only btw...

Answer (score 0):

Or another way.

```
test = "This is a sentence."
print "".join([char if char not in lowercase else uppercase[lowercase.index(char)] for char in test])
# THIS IS A SENTENCE.
```

Just to clarify, it is equivalent to this;

```
result = ""
for char in test:
    if char not in lowercase:
        result += char
    else:
        result += uppercase[lowercase.index(char)]
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ '
lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
```

First you can use zip and a dictionary comprehension to map the two letter lists.

```
mapping = {i: j for i, j in zip(lowercase, uppercase)}
```

Next you can use a list comprehension to map them.

```
def upper(s):
    S = ''.join([mapping.get(i, i) for i in s])
    return S
```

Following Paul Rooney's suggestion (using mapping.get()) means that the code is robust against unexpected characters. Only the characters in the dict will change.

Comment: This would fail if there were any characters in the string that were not a lower case letter. Suggested replacement `mapping.get(i, i)`

Comment: Thanks, that's a really useful suggestion. I've updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'hello world'
print "".join( [ chr(ord(c) - 32) if 97<=ord(c)<=122 else c for c in x ])
```

That should work.  It use the fact that ascii lowercase fall in the range[97,122] and the corresponding uppercase letters are encoded in the range 65-90.

Comment: or `return ''.join(chr(ord(c) - 32) if 'a' <= c <= 'z' else c for c in x)`

Comment: If x = `'anzac day'`. The result from this code is `'aNzaC DaY'`.

Comment: whoops, missed the less/greater than OR equal to

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as lowercase
from string import ascii_uppercase as uppercase

def upper(string):
    return ''.join([uppercase[lowercase.find(char)] for char in string])
```

You don't have to define the constants yourself when you can import them. What the only line in my upper function is doing is:

1. Iterating through the input string: `for char in string`
2. Finding the position of every char in the string `lowercase.find(char)`
3. Mapping it to the uppercase equivalent `uppercase[lowercase.find(char)]`
4. Joining each of the resulting list of uppercase chars in a single string `''.join([uppercase[lowercase.find(char)] for char in string])`

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you want to do this. here is an ASCII implementation

```
def upper(string):
result = list()
for x in string :
    result.append(convert(x))
return ''.join(result)

# convert each character to ascii and find its uppercase value
def convert(char):
ascil_value = ord(char) 
# ascii lower case are between 97 and 122
if( ascil_value >= 97 and ascil_value < 123):
    return chr(ascil_value - 32)
else:
    return char

upper('TesTing)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do know there is function in python called `upper()` that does the same thing, right?

```
s= "little boy doesn't cry"
print s.upper()
```

why are you writing it from scratch?